# How to append a child element to a root element by using DOM in android?

Tags: java, android, dom

How to append a child element to a root element by using DOM. Here is my XML file.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<array>

    <recipe>

        <name>Name First</name>
        <description>Description First</description>
        <instruction>Instruction First</instruction>

    </recipe>

    <recipe>

        <name>Name Second</name>
        <description>Description Second</description>
        <instruction>Instruction Second</instruction>

    </recipe>

</array>
```

I want to add a new `<recipe>` tag as a child of `<array>` tag. Here is my java code that I have developed in this respect, this code shows me log message properly and there is no error but it does not add new child, please help me and I identify that where I am going wrong. Thanks in advance.

```
private void addRecipeToMyRecipeFile(MyRecipeModel recipeModel)
    {
        MyRecipeModel mRecipe = recipeModel;
        MyRecipeHandler recipeHandler = new MyRecipeHandler();

// Here I get the content of XML file as a string and convert the string in XML format  
        Document doc = convertRecipesFileIntoXML(recipeHandler.getContentOfMyRecipesFileFromSDCard());
        Log.e("Doc", "convertRecipesFileIntoXML");

        final NodeList nodes_array = doc.getElementsByTagName(TAG_ARRAY);
        //We have encountered an <array> tag.
        Element rootArrayTag = (Element)nodes_array.item(0);
        Log.e("Element", "Array");

        // <recipe> elements
        Element recipe = doc.createElement(TAG_RECIPE);
        rootArrayTag.appendChild(recipe);
        Log.e("Element", "Recipe");

        // <name> is name of recipe
        Element name = doc.createElement(TAG_RECIPE_NAME);
        name.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(mRecipe.getMyRecipeName()));
        recipe.appendChild(name);
        Log.e("Element", "Name");

        // <description> is description of the recipe
        Element description = doc.createElement(TAG_RECIPE_DESCRIPTION);
        description.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(mRecipe.getMyRecipeDescription()));
        recipe.appendChild(description);
        Log.e("Element", "Description");

        // <instructions> elements
        Element instructions = doc.createElement(TAG_RECIPE_INSTRUCTION);
        instructions.appendChild(doc.createCDATASection(mRecipe.getMyRecipeInstruction()));
        recipe.appendChild(instructions);
        Log.e("Element", "Instruction");

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is problem in your code to manipulate DOM objects. But what is missing is that you need to output you DOM object somewhere, e.g. a file. Otherwise, the objects are just some memory blocks, and they don't automatically persist to your source file.

```
TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File(filepath));
transformer.transform(source, result);
```